# PyGTK TextBuffer adding Tags and reading text

Tags: application-development, python, pygtk

As in topic I have TextView() and TextBuffer() added to it, I also have Tags created so when I select text and click button it will make text BOLD or something. Up to this point all works well, now I need to be able to go through all text in TextView and find what Tag is applied and where, I need this so I can format text by adding stuff before and after tagged text.

here is part of the code:

```
    self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
    self.buffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
    self.scrolledwindow.add(self.textview)
    self.textview.show()

    self.tag_bold = self.buffer.create_tag("bold", weight=Pango.Weight.BOLD)
```

It would be best if I could get output like, "test text" is "bold".

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Here's the correct function to use:
`Gtk.TextIter.forward_to_tag_toggle()`

here's an example that generates a list of all bolded words:

```
    start = self.textbuffer.get_start_iter()
    bolded=[]
    while start.forward_to_tag_toggle(self.tag_bold):
        begin=start.copy()
        start.forward_to_tag_toggle(self.tag_bold)
        bolded.append(self.textbuffer.get_text(begin,start,False))
    print bolded
```

While you are using pygi (not pyGTK; note the uppercase Gtk in your functions), many of the pyGTK functions are still valid though may require some tweaking. You can get documentation [here](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextiter.html#method-gtktextiter--copy) for gtk.textiter in pygtk.

**OLD ANSWER:**
Not sure if this is the optimal way, but I found that you could iterate over each character (maybe each word if you want) and test whether the character has the tag you want:  Here's a simple function to do that:

```
    start = self.textbuffer.get_start_iter()
    plus = self.textbuffer.get_start_iter()
    bolded=''
    while plus.forward_char():
        if start.has_tag(self.tag_bold):
            bolded=bolded+(start.get_text(plus))
        start.forward_char()
    print bolded
```

you can also use the Gtk.TextIter get_tags() method to get what tags a character has.

Finally, what may work better is to store the bounds in some list when you apply the tags to begin with.

Comment: Thank you @Ian B. 
I have adopted your code to my program and it works for me.